# Rake Task Starts But Stops abruptly when executed via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a set of rake tasks that run on the production server, its detached from the main thread, and happens in the background

here is the code to execute it

```
def vehicle
    @estate = Estate.find(@estate_id)
    @date_string = @login_month.strftime("%m%Y")
    system("rake udpms:process_only_vehicle[#{@date_string},#{@estate_id}] &")
    redirect_to :controller => "reports/error_messages", :message => "Processing will happen in the background and reports will be refreshed after two minutes", :target => "_blank"
  end
```

when this code is executed via the url route, it runs the rake task, i can see if i check the active processes on the production machine, but it ends abruptly after about 10 seconds.

```
ps axl | grep rake
```

this is the it shows

```
ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/rake udpms:process_only_vehicle[082012,5]
```

if i execute the same same rake task in the app folder in the terminal it runs with out any errors. This runs without any issues on the dev machine. (OSX). Server is Mint. Rake version is the same on both. there is only one version of the gem.

since its the production server there are no logs (other than the produciton.log, and its no help). any help on how i go about debugging this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: If the rake task 'udpms:process_only_vehicle' is your custom task, you can add some logging in it, to debug what happened. Rails.logger.info will be very useful, because it will log to production.log :D

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to fire off rake tasks from controller actions. I suggests wrapping the functionality into a class and execute it via rake or from the controller separately.

If you insist of doing it the way you are doing it now, ensure you are setting the environment as well: `rake RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} ...`. My guess is that it talks 10 seconds to load the Rails environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because your server software reaps requests that take longer than 10 seconds to respond. Despite the fact you're kicking off a rake task, it still has to wait for that `system` call to execute: if it takes awhile then the task will be terminated and the server worker returned to the worker pool.

In a more general sense, this is not the appropriate way to make a task happen in the background. You probably want to use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/) or [Delayed Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/), which enqueue tasks and run them in the background for you.